# how to use one field value to update another one in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following document:

```
{
    "logout_time": null,
    "duration": null,
    "_id": "5e8e8dd2b0c2a30ad12973f9",
    "user_id": "5e8109ea5bc5822aa531a57d",
    "comp_id": "5e8d16a0c1834fd3d8e9e1eb",
    "org_id": "5e8c7a34c358958a58be4755",
    "login_time": "2020-03-16T05:29:34.000Z",
    "server_time": "2020-04-09T02:52:02.646Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I am using mongoose and nodeJS. now when I get logout time I update it in document using following function:

```
async function logOut(user_id, comp_id, time) {
  try {
    let updateObj = await Session.updateMany(
      { user_id: user_id, comp_id: comp_id, logout_time: null },
      {
        $set: {
          logout_time: time,
        },
      }
    );
    return {
      status: "success",
      msg: "Logged Out successfully",
      update_info: updateObj,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return { status: "failed", message: err.message };
  }
}
```

but now I want to update duration as logout time - login time when I get logout time, I tried many things but can't get it done using mongoose.
I am new to mongo and had used MySQL.

I Tried following but its not working:

```
async function logOut(user_id, comp_id, time) {
  try {
    let updateObj = await Session.updateMany(
      { user_id: user_id, comp_id: comp_id, logout_time: null },
      {
        $set: {
          logout_time: time,
          duration: { $subtract: [Date(time), "$login_time"] },
        },
      }
    );
    return {
      status: "success",
      msg: "Logged Out successfully",
      update_info: updateObj,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return { status: "failed", message: err.message };
  }
}
```

so my question is how can we update a field in mongoDB using other field's value?

Comment: What version of mongoDB are you using?

Comment: mongoDB version 4.2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) is an aggregation pipeline operators so you need to use it in aggregation. Fortunately, starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use the aggregation pipeline for update operations. Since you're using mongoDB version 4.2.2 so the below should work:

```
Session.updateMany(
  { user_id: user_id, comp_id: comp_id, logout_time: null },
  [{
    $set: {
      logout_time: new Date(time),
      duration: { $subtract: [new Date(time), "$login_time"] },
    },
  }]
)
```

See: [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: It is give me error :
cant $subtract adate from a string

Comment: please update your answer  and thanks it was very helpful 
i tried this before but i missed [ ] around $set

Comment: Updated refer to your note.

Comment: also after using aggregation logout time started to save as string and not as date even though data type date is mention in mongoose schema.

but changing logout_time: time to logout_time: new Date(time) solved it 

if possible add this change to your ans